# Backup comments from social database on SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, backup, database, social

We have almost all our sites on SharePoint 2013 now and are working towards shutting our 2010 environment Down.

One of the last sites on 2010 have used the Note Board function on pages as a Means of commenting.

We have migrated all content to a 2013 site, but the comments are placed on the user profiles in the Social database and not on the pages themselves.

Is there any way to extract ALL comments from the social db to a file that we can use for backup. It doesn't need to be used for migration purposes, it just needs to be a file, in which we can lookup a given comment for a given page if the need arises. So an Excel-file would be handy.

Does anybody know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

In your case I'd just restore a backup copy of the social database and export the data directly from the SocialComments table

For that I'd use SQL Server Management Studio to construct a T-SQL query and outputting the comments to a file that can then be opened with Excel or text editor.

Example of SQL query outputting all fields (some of which you probably won't be interested in):

```
SELECT 
     [PartitionID]
    ,[UrlID]
    ,[LastModifiedTime]
    ,[User_RecordID]
    ,[CommentID]
    ,[Comment]
    ,[Title]
    ,[IsHighPriority]
FROM 
    [SocialComments]
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Sadly the resulting file looks a bit muddled in Excel. Perhaps that has to do with the way I import it, but I've tried more or less every scenario. Is there a way to select EVERY field from [SocialComments]?